# XPath - Select all coaches of teams who havn't won a game

Tags: xpath

I have an XML file with two types of elements:

```
<team name="n1" coach="c1"></team>

<game teams="t1 t2" winner="t2"></game>
```

I want to select the coaches of all teams who havn't won any game.
What I've tried is

```
//team[count(//game[@winner=@name])=0]/@coach
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//team[not(@name=//game/@winner)]/@coach
```

It selects

```
COACHES OF ANY TEAM
//team                           /@coach
      THAT DOES NOT
      [not(                    )]
           HAVE A @NAME EQUAL TO ANY @WINNER
           @name=//game/@winner
```

Comment: I've tried it here: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm but it doesn't seem to work, even though your solution makes sense to me (not that my opinion counts since I've known XPath for 3 hours or so :)

Comment: @Shmoopy It worked for my little test. Obviously, I made my test different from your input data and something is wrong there. Could you give us a complete XML example and an expected output? Also, what exactly was wrong? Did it match anything, did it throw an error, did it match too much?

Comment: Sure. http://pastebin.com/S38Gar7L (it's a bit differnt than I posted but nothing that should matter) and I've tried it here: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Comment: @Shmoopy All [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php and http://www.xpathtester.com/ returned `Mourinho` and `Fergusson` to me. To be honest, I have no idea why the XPath testbed is returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the coaches of teams that didn't win any game, including coaches not assigned to any team.

```
//coach[not(@name=//team[@name=//game/@winner]/@coach)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might look overkill, but you can use MS SQL 2005/2008 Express to test your xpath.
Or you can use http://sqlfiddle.com to test it online.

See this example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml ='<db>
            <team name="chelsea" coach="mourinho"><owner>abramovich</owner><owner>abramovich2</owner></team>
            <team name="arsenal" coach="venger"><owner>poorguy</owner></team>
            <team name="manchester" coach="ferguson"><owner>richguy</owner></team>
            <coach name="mourinho"></coach>
            <coach name="venger"></coach>
            <coach name="ferguson"></coach>
            <coach name="nobody"></coach>
            <game teams="chelsea arsenal" winner="arsenal"></game>
            <game teams="manchester arsenal" winner="manchester"></game>
    </db>'

SELECT 
  name = x.value('@name','varchar(100)')
, element = x.query('.') 
FROM @xml.nodes('//coach[not(@name=//team[@name=//game/@winner]/@coach)]')  AS T(x)

-- OUTPUT
name        element
mourinho    <coach name="mourinho" />
nobody      <coach name="nobody" />
```